# How can I get the object from a button's value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use the map method on an array of objects to create a button:

```
arrayOfObjects.map(obj => ( 
  <button value={obj} onClick={handleClick} key={obj._id}>
    {obj.name}
  </button>
```

where:

```
const handleClick = ({ target }) => {
  const obj = target.value
  onClick(obj) // this onClick is a prop from another React function component
}
```

How do I get the object itself ? With this, I get the following:
[The onClick method would set the state of my component but it is not what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbqZ4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the handleClick function with the object:

```
const handleClick = (obj) => () => {
  onClick(obj) 
}
```

and with the buttons:

```
arrayOfObjects.map(obj => ( 
  <button onClick={handleClick(obj)} key={obj._id}>
    {obj.name}
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
arrayOfObjects.map(obj => ( 
  <button :value=obj onClick="handleClick" :key=obj._id>
    {{obj.name}}
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Value gets stored as a string, not an object.

You should instead do something like

```
arrayOfObjects.map(obj => ( 
  <button onClick={()=>onClick(obj)} key={obj._id}>
    {obj.name}
  </button>
```